# If $ Q(x)= x^2-5x+1 $ , find $ \frac {Q(5+h)-Q(5)}{h} $

Tags: functions

If $ Q(x)= x^2-5x+1 $ , find $ \dfrac {Q(5+h)-Q(5)}{h} $

can someone show the steps to reach the answer of $h+5$?

I got it down to $\frac{h^2+5h-2}{h}$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{Q(5+h)-Q(5)}{h}$$

I get this:

$$\frac{h^2+10h+25-5h-25+1-1}{h}$$

$$\frac{h^2+5h}{h}$$

$$h+5$$

Comment: Thank you! Made a sign error

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $Q(5+h) = (5+h)^2 - 5(5+h) +1=...$

Comment: I got it down to $\frac{h^2+5h-2}{h}$

Comment: There should be no $-2$, you got a sign wrong somewhere.